# How to put (3n-1) formula into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, css-selectors, formula

I built a 3 column gallery and need each middle element (3n-1) of it to get .portfolio-margin class. Can't use css :nth-child as it refers to all `.element`, but I only want to count the visible ones.

I want add the `portfolio-margin` class to the elements in the array of `:visible` elements with the indexes 0, 2, 5, 8, 11, etc. How can I do this with the index (`i`) of a `.each()` loop?

```
$('.element:visible').each(function (i) {
    if (i === 2 || i === 5 || i === 8 || i === 11 .....) {
        $(this).addClass('portfolio-margin');
    }
});
```

Comment: Other than the n=0 case, `if (i%3 === 2)` would catch all 3n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple solutions. You can adapt your code to calculate position depending on index.

```
$('.element:visible').each(function (i) {
     if ( i % 3 - 1 === 0 ) $(this).addClass('portfolio-margin');
});
```

Comment: `i%3-1 === 0` would give you every first element. Should be `i%3 === 2`